# How to replace Alternator out (2001 Nissan Sentra) [pictures inside]

Tags: nissan, alternator, belt, serpentine-belt

I am trying to remove the Alternator on my Nissan Sentra 2001. I believe I need to take the alternator belt off. It's tightly on the pulley - see picture [image]

How to make the belt loose? I am told that there should be a tensioner bolt head and it has a very long thread which screws into the backside of the center bolt/nut that is 90 degrees of the center bolt/nut but I cannot find it.

Is it in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off [this diagram](http://www.justanswer.com/nissan/2wqbs-change-belt-nissan-sentra-2001.html), the adjusting bolt is not present in the pictures you provided:

[image: Nissan Sentra 2001 Belt Diagram]

It looks like your Sentra has air-conditioning, which means that your belt tensioning mechanism sits above the power steering pump (leftmost belt-driven component).

Comment: It is visible in the first picture if you look behind the idler/tensioner pulley you can see a threaded rod that points towards the front of the car. It also shows this on the bottom left diagram of the image you posted.

Comment: Thanks, the picture helped. It was grease covered but was finally able to find it

Answer (score 5):

Try to get hold of a workshop manual; failing that, a Chiltons or Haynes manual for that car. I've just checked the Haynes, and it does show the Alternator replacement in some detail.

A couple of major hints; firstly, you get much better access going in through the passenger wheel-well. Take the wheel off, and the plastic shield between the wheel-well and the engine compartment, and the alternator will be staring you in the face.

Secondly, the alternator sits on top of the A/C Compressor. You'll *think* you can work around it, but you can't. It has to be moved, so you can get to the alternator bolt correctly. Undo the four compressor bolts, and *move* the compressor out of the way - do NOT disconnect any lines to the compressor, or you'll lose all refrigerant, the ozone layer will shrink a little, and somewhere, a small kitten will die (OK, not sure about the kitten).

Comment: noob here. So is this the manual i should be getting for the sentra 2001? http://www.haynes.com/products/productID/442

Comment: IIRC you can remove the fan shroud to get to the rear bolt on the 1.8 and pull the alternator through the top.

Comment: @user1406716: Yes, that's the correct Haynes manual. Ben: It's been a while since I last did it (5 times in two weeks - kept getting bad alternators!) - but you may be correct. I'm hoping I never need to do it again! :)

Answer (score 2):

Different year same engine.

[image]

Your image

[image]

Loosen the idler pulley nut. And per the posted image loosen the adjuster to remove the belt.

You don't have to remove the AC compressor to R&R the alternator on the 1.8. You can remove the fan shroud to access the lower bolt on the alternator and pull the alternator through the top.

Comment: do you think i can do it from the top itself or need to go under the car or take the wheel off?

Comment: you can probably do the whole thing without removing the wheel. the fan shroud will have to come off this way though.

Comment: oh the fan shroud in the front on the radiator? Oh ok... that seems daunting but will try today

Answer (score 0):

Yes the tensioner is to the left of the alternator - in the pictures above. Slightly loosen the main bolt on the tensioner - not too much. This will allow you to loosen the adjustment rod BEHIND the tensioner, which creates slack and loosens the belt. You should be able to see it - it will look like a threaded rod. Probably a good time to replace the belt and the tensioner, while you are in there... I know that is normal procedure on most vehicles... and the oil leak if possible. Oil will degrade the belt over time.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Adjusting-Nissan-Sentra-Serpentine-Belts-1/

Comment: This answer is valid for non-AC configurations, but the OP seems to have an AC compressor.